# Add a MouseListener to painted components

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I have the following class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {

        // This label draws two black rectangles to the screen.
        JLabel label = new JLabel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // clears the screen
                g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 75); // draws first rect
                g.fillRect(150, 50, 50, 75); // draws second rect
            }
        };

        // adds the label to the frame
        add(label);

        // frame properties
        setSize(250, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This class draws to rectangles to the screen. All is working fine. But I'd like to add a MouseListener to both rectangles, so I know when the user clicks on one of the two rectangles. This is only an example. There could also be twenty or more rectangles, not only two. How do I add a MouseListener to every rectangle I draw? Using the `mouseClicked()` method (implemented by the MouseListener) I'd then like to get the rectangle that was clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: add listner to lable and detect which one is clicked by mouse coordinates

Comment: @FastSnail Could you explain this by posting a piece of code?

Comment: @DejoriDavid: Create an `abstract` class called `Shape`. Then your real shapes such as `Rectangle`, `Square`, `Circle` or any other shape you have must `extends` the Shape. Create an abstract method called `public boolean isPointWithinArea(Point p);` for you Shape class. So each of your real shapes must implement this method. Using a little math you can implement this method for each of the real shapes. Then as FastSnail said, you should add a `mouseListener` to your frame which shapes are being painted on. Then in that mouseListener you can get the clicked point (x,y) and pass it to shapes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't extend a JLabel for custom painting. You extend either a `JPanel` or a `JComponent`.
2. Don't hardcode the painting of the Rectangles in the paintComponent() method.

In the constructor of your class that does the custom painting you need to create an `ArrayList` to hold the `Rectangles` that you want to paint. Something like:

```
public RectanglePanel extends JPanel
{
    List<Rectangles> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangles>();

    public RectanglePanel()
    {
        rectangles.add( new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 75) );
        rectangles.add( new Rectangle(150, 50, 50, 75) );
    }
}
```

Now in the custom painting code you iterated through the `List` and paint all the `Rectangles`:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g); // this will clear the background for you

    for (Rectangle r: rectangles)
    {
        g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
    }
}
```

Now in the `MouseListener` you can use the `contains(...)` method of the `Rectangle` to see which `Rectangle` was clicked:

```
@Override
protected void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    for (Rectangle r: rectangles)
    {
        if (r.contains(e.getPoint())
           // do something
    }
}
```

This is a far more flexible solution that allows you to add many more Rectangles with a single line of code.

Comment: This works great for click and move events, but it doesn't work for enter and exit because  enter and exit is called once for the JPanel. Any suggestions/ideas how to make it work when mouse enters/exits a drawn rectangle?

Comment: You use a MouseMotionListener and handle the mouseMoved event. The logic would basically be the same as the mouseClicked event. That is you still need to iterate through all the Rectangles to determine if you just entered a rectangle or exited a rectangle.

Comment: Thanks @camickr. I managed to recreate the mouseEntered/mouseExited events by using the mouseMoved event rectangles, storing them in a set, and calculating the difference between the previous and new moved rectangles. This way I could track the mouseEntered/mouseExited events very consistently.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the mouse listener for the label like this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {

        // This label draws two black rectangles to the screen.
        JLabel label = new JLabel() {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // clears the screen
                g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 75); // draws first rect
                g.fillRect(150, 50, 50, 75); // draws second rect
            }
        };

        // adds the label to the frame
        add(label);

        label.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                int x = evt.getX();
                int y = evt.getY();

                if (x >= 50 && x < 100 && y >= 50 && y <= 125) {
                    rectangleClicked(1);
                } 
                else if (x >= 150 && x < 200 && y >= 50 && y <= 125) {
                    rectangleClicked(2);
                }

            }
        });
        // frame properties
        setSize(250, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void rectangleClicked(int r) {
        System.out.println("Rectangle " + r + " clicked.");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Since you are applying this to several rectangles, you may have to use variables and some formula in place of the fix values for flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

First off I would suggest using javafx, The graphics scene would be idea for this case.

For swing you could create a awt.Component and take care of the layout/position on your own.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

/**
 *  Created by matt on 8/9/15.
 */
public class ClickableTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("painting example");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        Component panelB = new JPanel(){
            Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,100, 100);
            public boolean contains(int x, int y){
                return circle.contains(x,y);
            }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                ((Graphics2D)g).fill(circle);
            }
        };
        panelB.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
                System.out.println("clicked");
            }
        });

        //now swing will not modify the size of panel be.
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(panelB);

        panelB.setBounds(300, 300, 100, 100);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

This could certainly be improved.